# how to pass headers in http call in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, http-headers, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

I am developing mobile application in cordova/phonegap. I am using angularJS for front-end. I am calling services which required 'API-KEY' attribute as header in post request.

I show some documentations, and tried with those way. but not worked.

```
postServiceDataWithHeader: function (url, data) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {
                    'user-Token': $rootScope.user.APIKEY,
                    'content-Type': 'Application/Json'
                }
            }
            $http(req).success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Server failed to save data");
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

I tried to add headers in call with,

```
JodoModule.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['user-Token'] = 'finding???';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
});
```

and second approach was,

```
JodoModule.run(['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {    
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w';    
}]);
```

I am able to call services, but on server side, I am not getting header values, even in fiddler also headers are not passed.

What is the reason ? Do I need to add anything else in code for passing headers for each POST request. ?

Answer (score 1):

I've made working plunker for you using one of yours approach

http://plnkr.co/edit/36Dq6UXgyeMEXOzycrua?p=preview

```
app.config(function ( $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['User-Token'] = 'finding???';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
});
```

Although if it's CORS you have to add 'User-Token' to accepted headers
i.e. for apache2

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, user-token, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: On server side, I am allowing all origins and all headers.
When I am calling service via fiddler by adding headers its working fine.
But when I calling service via angular application, its not working on server side... 

When I pass header from fiddler, it show me each header as attribute,
ie.
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:62676
Content-Length: 0
user-token: 'this is key'.....

But when I pass headers via application, it show all headers in single attribute without their values with ,
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, user-token, content-type.

Comment: You mean it shows ` Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, user-token, content-type` in request headers when you look in developer tools in browser?

Comment: And it will not, it's the same in my plunker, but in return response you can see printed headers and it's values